# How do I fix the message "You didn't really think you could install Ruby through npm, did you?"

Tags: ruby, node.js, macos

I'm trying to install homebrew on my Mac OSX Yosemite machine.  When I try to follow the conventional installation process:

$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

I keep getting the message in my terminal "You didn't really think you could install Ruby through npm, did you?"

To my knowledge, Yosemite comes with Ruby 2.0 installed in the PATH.  If this is so, why do I keep getting this message and how do I install Ruby and Homebrew.

I looked up a number of examples online but every example for installing Homebrew requires ruby and every example for installing Ruby requires Homebrew.

SMH, why not give me a message of what I need to do instead of a bullshit comedy message?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `/usr/bin/ruby` instead of plain `ruby` as already suggested will work.

However, this is only applying a bandaid; you should be stopping the bleeding, because the inane npm ruby will still be in your path and may come back to bite you in the rear-end.

A more sane approach would be to *un*-install the npm ruby. Something like:

```
npm uninstall -g ruby
```

Comment: Ah nice to see where that was actually coming from. I'm going to see if the npm team might consider unpublishing it.

Answer (score 2):

Try the same command but starting with `/usr/bin/ruby` which is the full absolute path to the ruby that is bundled with OS X. If you type `which ruby` my guess is you are running a different program also named "ruby" that is "not the droids you are looking for" if you know what I mean. Another good sanity check is `/usr/bin/ruby -v` should print something similar to "ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]".

Comment: I'm a noob
How do I get to /usr/bin/ruby from the command line?
I tried to cd usr and cd /usr/bin/ruby but it says No such file or directory.

Finally I'm not using a program called ruby anywhere. when I do ruby -v it is at the highest level of the terminal

Comment: Just type it directly. Here's the entire command to type: `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"` then hit ENTER. That's it. Nothing more.

Comment: You can run `ls /usr/bin/ruby`. If that says "no such file or directory" then you've managed to delete the ruby bundled with OSX and you'll need some guidance to repair that or install ruby manually.